# Geocoder.getFromLocationName() throws "Service not available" exception on Android 4 with Google Maps V2

Tags: android, geocoding, google-maps-android-api-2

The method `Geocoder.getFromLocationName()` throws the exception `Service not available` on Android 4.1, even if `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` returns `SUCCESS` and `Geocoder.isPresent()` returns `true`.
Is there any official example for geocoding in the new Google Maps v2 API?

Comment: I found a workaround for this: reboot the device. But it's not a solution...

Comment: I'm still finding a way to solve this bug. Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas? Seems the Geocoder doesn't work on Android 4, with Google Maps V2

Answer (score 3):

`Geocoder` is not related to Google Maps Android API v2.

You may want to use [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) directly instead of `Geocoder`, which gives you limited amount of data and might be affected by device or Android version specific problems.

Comment: I didn't know that Geocoder is not related to the v2 API. 
Anyway, have I to use [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) method?

Comment: I see there are problems even with Google Geocoding API so I have to implement a solution that includes Geocoder class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

try this .....

```
      public  JSONObject getLocationFormGoogle(String placesName) {

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +placesName+"&ka&sensor=false");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}

public  LatLng getLatLng(JSONObject jsonObject) {

    Double lon = new Double(0);
    Double lat = new Double(0);

    try {

        lon = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lng");

        lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lat");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new LatLng(lat,lon);

}



LatLng Source =getLatLng(getLocationFormGoogle(placesName));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it worked perfectly. just wanted to now that if the name has spaces it will crash. so it would be a nice idea to edit the code to replace the white space with a `%20` in the `placesName` before doing the request to avoid the crash