# Frequent OVER_QUERY_LIMIT using Google Places API KEY even before the No. of limitation

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

We are using Google Places API KEY in order to use 'Search' provided from Google and as far as we know the number of usage for API KEY is limited to 100,000 times  per day.

However, we frequently kept on getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT even before searching 100,000 times and receive "No Result" on the screen. The debug result was as we said 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT'.

Is there any case and reason for OVER_QUERY_LIMIT to be appeared? 
What is the solution for this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mobile connection your problem may reside in your mobile operator. The vast majority of operators use a technique called NAT overloading and assign the same external IP to a number of devices. If your operator assigns a very large number of devices to a single IP and a number of them uses similar services, everyone will have a problem, as all requests will appear to stem from the same IP.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770659/google-maps-geocoding-api-v3-search-ok-with-wifi-but-responses-over-query-limit) question has interesting answers to this problem, that I encountered too.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find 3 throttle limits for the places api, given by google.

1. 10 api calls per every 1 second
2. 100 api calls per every 100 seconds
3. 50,000 api calls per 1 day

If I were to go over any of these limits, I would receive the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error and it would return no results for that given address.

I found a way to have my program sleep for 11 seconds after calling the places api with a dataset of 10 addresses. Then the program would call the places api with a new dataset of 10 address. This solution gets around the 10calls/second and the 100calls/100seconds throttle limits. However, I did run into the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error once I tried my 25th dataset of 10 address (after 240 api calls). So it is clear that there are other throttles not published to help protect the google maps platform.

But, I did see that the limits mentioned above may be changed if you get in contact with the google api help team and sort it out with them.