# How to get latitude and longitude bounds by city/country name android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am searching Latitude and longitude bounds in google map for a specific city. I got the example to implement for country name India.

```
private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_INDIA = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(23.63936, 68.14712), new LatLng(28.20453, 97.34466));
```

Now, I want to set it for my chosen country. Where to find those two point Latitude and Longitude for specific area.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873076/get-latitude-and-longitude-from-city-name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-address

Comment: go through these links

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

```
 String location=cityName;
String inputLine = "";
String result = ""
location=location.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
String myUrl="http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="+location+"&output=csv";
try{
 URL url=new URL(myUrl);
 URLConnection urlConnection=url.openConnection();
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
 InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  result=inputLine;
  }
  String lat = result.substring(6, result.lastIndexOf(","));
  String longi = result.substring(result.lastIndexOf(",") + 1);
 }
 catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: OP is asking how he can get latitude and longitude for a specific area, not the address for a specific latitude and longitude

Comment: use google map api for that see the code i have edited